# Devops pipline looking for keyvault in wrong subscription

Tags: azure-devops, terraform

Bit of an odd one.. When I run my pipline to add some new resources, it is failing at terraform plan with a 403 error.

Error:  retrieving Vault: (Name "kv-name" / Resource Group "rg-name"): keyvault.VaultsClient#Get: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailed" Message="The client '1' with object id '1' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/read' over scope '/subscriptions/3/resourceGroups/-rg/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/kv' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."

Trouble is , the KV doesn't exist in the given subscription but is in a different one, I cant understand why its trying to find it in that sub.

Any thoughts? I can see the scope is invalid, but dont know why

Its just standard code to add an extension to a function app. Works fine on others, But t his one cant get past plan, doesnt even get to my code.

Comment: Please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Post your YAML. You need to show where you're setting the subscription during your `terraform init`.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out what I was doing wrong.
I had a data block calling a keyvault from a different subscription in my terraform and it kept on trying to look for other KVs in that same sub.
I have moved the secrets all under one sub for now, but am also looking at variable groups in my YAML to help me out.